# Turing's argument that computable sequences are enumerable

Tags: computability, turing-machines

In Turing's paper from 1936, he shows how the following counter-argument is a fallacy:

> If the computable sequences are enumerable, let $\alpha_n$ be the $n$-th computable sequence, and let $\phi_n(m)$ be the $m$-th figure in $\alpha_n$. Let $\beta$ be the sequence with $1 - \phi_n(n)$ as its $n$-th figure. Since $\beta$ is computable, there exists a number $K$ such that $1 - \phi_n(n) = \phi_K(n)$ all $n$. Putting $n = K$, we have $1 = 2\phi_K(K)$, i.e. $1$ is even. This is impossible. The computable sequences are therefore not enumerable.

Turing writes that

> The fallacy lies in the assumption that $\beta$ is computable

However, I'm perplexed by another point in that reasoning.
As I understand it, it firstly choses an arbitrary $n$, then defines $\alpha_n$, and then says that $\exists K \in N,\; \forall n,\; 1 - \phi_n(n) = \phi_K(n)$ ("there exists a number $K$ such that $1 - \phi_n(n) = \phi_K(n)$ all $n$").
So although $n$ has been set, this still supposes $n$ can be arbitrary.

Again, the following reads "Putting $n = K$", which contradicts the fact that $n$ was already picked.

Let aside the fallacy Turing aims to highlight, am I wrong in my understanding of this reasoning?

Comment: Until the sentence "Putting $n = K$ ...", all the $n$s before that should be read as "for all $n$". For example, $\beta$ is the sequence so that, for all $n$, $\beta(n) = 1 - \phi_n(n)$. The proof begins with the assumption that the function $\phi_n(m)$ is computable, meaning there is a single algorithm that for all $n$ and $m$ produces $\phi_n(m)$.

Comment: @CarlMummert That's what I suspected; however, $K$ still depends upon $n$, doesn't it? So how could one put $n = K$?

Comment: $K$ does not depend on $n$. Because $\beta$ is a computable sequence, and every computable sequence is of the form $\alpha_n$ for some $n$, there must be some $K$ so that $\beta = \alpha_K$.

Comment: So if I got it right, we take a $n$, then define $\beta$ as the sequence $\alpha_n$ with the $n$-th digit inversed, then we say there exists a $K$ such that $\beta = \alpha_K$, is that so?

Comment: I think so, We define $\beta$ so that, for every $n$, the $n$th digit of $\beta$ is obtained by reversing the $n$th digit of $\alpha_n$. So $\beta(2)$ is the opposite of the second digit of $\alpha_$, $\beta(10)$ is the opposite of the $10$th digit of $\alpha_{10}$, etc.    Now, if the entire sequence of sequences $(\alpha_n)$ was computable by some algorithm, then $\beta$ would also be computable by using that algorithm.

Comment: @CarlMummert I finally got it. I'm having a hard time understanding Turing's somewhat-old style... thanks a lot!